# Php variable in stripe form

Tags: php, html

Hello guys I am trying to use a php variable in the stripe simple implementation
where the amount will be taken from a database only if the person has logged in otherwise the login button will be shown. My problem is that when I put the code in the echo statement the php variable($amount) is not passed properly anymore.Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){
                 $newId = $_SESSION['u_id'];
              $sql = "SELECT Amount FROM costumers WHERE id='$newId'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $amount=$row['Amount'];
            }
                echo'<form class = "payment" action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
<script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="pk_test"
  data-amount="$amount"
  data-name="Company"
  data-description="Card Payment"
  data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
  data-locale="auto">
</script>
     <script>

        document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = \'none\';
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="yourCustomClass">Pay with Card</button>
</form>';
            } else{
                    echo'<div class="logInButton" onclick = "location.href = \'loginindex.php\'">
            <a href="loginindex.php">Login/Sign up</a></div>';
                }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing the quotes on your `echo` statement into double quotes - `"`, and perhaps (for readability as well) show where you're using variables using curly braces. As such `echo "data-amount='{$amount}'"`

Comment: Also, just for readability and ease of use, when you have a lengthy amount of HTML, you're better off escaping PHP and dropping back in to it only when you need to. Then the line in question becomes `data-amount:="<?php echo $amount; ?>"`

Comment: What about the double quotes in the rest of the code?

Comment: I want the form to be shown I only if the person has logged in so i think that the whole code has to be in an echo but im not very good with php

Answer (score 0):

first try to use sprintf on your echo to pass the $amount value like this :

```
echo sprintf("<form class = 'payment' action='/your-server-side-code' method='POST'>
<script
  src='https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js' class='stripe-button'
  data-key='pk_test'
  data-amount='%s'
  data-name='Company'
  data-description='Card Payment'
  data-image='https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png'
  data-locale='auto'>
</script>
     <script>

        document.getElementsByClassName('stripe-button-el')[0].style.display = 'none';
    </script>
    <button type='submit' class='yourCustomClass'>Pay with Card</button>
</form>",$amount);
```

Then, check the value of $amount by typing var_dump($amount) , it's type should be a string.

I use PDO instead of MYSQLI , so for better parsing the id and getting value of amount you can use this :

```
$db=new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=madb","user","mdp");
$sql = "SELECT Amount FROM costumers WHERE id= ?";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute([$newId]);
$amount=($result->rowCount()!=0) ? $result->fetch()['Amount'] : "noValue";
```

Instead of :

```
$sql = "SELECT Amount FROM costumers WHERE id='$newId'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $amount=$row['Amount'];
        }
```

Good luck.